# I need oAuth2.0 bundle for Symfony 3.1

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a new application using Symfony 3.1. I'm trying to find the oAuth2.0 bundle for the API build. I didn't find suitable bundle for the latest symfony version. I need help on getting the new bundle or suggest me any other alternative if anything available.

Comment: as client or as a server?

Comment: As server: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle

Comment: As client: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle